# Scaning images using trivy

Tags: image, trivy

How do you scan images which are not pushed to repositories but are present locally using trivy image scanner?
I am getting the below error while scanning a local image

```
FATAL   image scan error: scan error: unable to initialize a scanner: unable to initialize a docker scanner: 4 errors occurred:
    * unable to inspect the image (test): Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
    * containerd socket not found: /run/containerd/containerd.sock
    * unable to initialize Podman client: no podman socket found: stat podman/podman.sock: no such file or directory
    * GET https://index.docker.io/v2/library/test/manifests/latest: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:library/ajinkya Type:repository]]
```

But I can scan images by pulling images from docker hub.